# Como copiar o caminho de um arquivo selecionado no Window Explorer?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Como copiar o caminho completo contendo o nome do arquivo para o *clipboard* usando o "shortcut" <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>?
Por exemplo: Dentro do windows explorer selecionar um arquivo (`teste.py`) usando o <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> e depois o <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> em um editor de texto. Tento o resultado final: `c:\temp\teste.py`

Estou pensando inicialmente em utilizar o *widget* do Windows Explorer da função `subprocess.Popen`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"c:\temp\"')
```

Uma vez capturado o caminho do arquivo posso copiá-lo no *clipboard* usando a uma sub-rotina similar abaixo:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
mypath = "c:/temp/teste.py"
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append(mypath)
r.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o módulo [win32clipboard](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32clipboard.html) do [PyWin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) (Muito provavelmente você já o tem instalado). A função GetClipboardData() (Que geralmente é usada pra texto) aceita um parâmetro de especificação de formato do que está no clipboard, e no caso, você pode passar a constante de valor 15 (CF_HDROP) utilizada pra mover / copiar arquivos pelo CTR + C e CTR + V pelo Windows. Eu elaborei uma breve função get_path_of_file_on_clipboard para ilustrar:

```
from win32clipboard import OpenClipboard, GetClipboardData, CloseClipboard

def get_path_of_file_on_clipboard():
    CF_HDROP = 15
    OpenClipboard()
    data = "No file was selected."
    try:
        data = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
    except TypeError:
        print("ERROR: You must copy a FILE to the clipboard.")
    finally:
        CloseClipboard()
    return data

print(get_path_of_file_on_clipboard())
```

Essa função retorna uma string com o caminho absoluto para o arquivo que foi passado para o clipboard (Com CTR + C). Uma vez tendo obtido este caminho, basta adaptar para a sua aplicação com Tkinter (É só capturar o evento de CTR + V e inserir essa string onde quiser).